# Is it possible to set up a test container that points to multiple mariadb databases?

Tags: java, testcontainers

Trying to get some tests working in quarkus. I can set up multiple databases in the quarkus application.properties file and everything works fine.  Can't get my tests to run on multiple datasources. I can connect to one or the other but not both. Something like this:

```
      private static final MariaDBContainer DATABASE = 
  new MariaDBContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse(DOCKER_IMAGE).asCompatibleSubstituteFor("mariadb"))
                    .withDatabaseName(FIRST_DB_NAME)
                    .withUsername(DB_USER)
                    .withPassword(DB_PASS)
                    .withDatabaseName(SECOND_DB_NAME)
                    .withUsername(DB_USER)
                    .withPassword(DB_PASS);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want two database servers, you can duplicate your container setup:

```
@Container
static final MariaDBContainer DATABASE_ONE =
  new MariaDBContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("mariadb:10.3.6"))
    .withDatabaseName("maindb")
    .withUsername("duke")
    .withPassword("duke");

@Container
static final MariaDBContainer DATABASE_TWO =
  new MariaDBContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("mariadb:10.3.6"))
    .withDatabaseName("seconddb")
    .withUsername("duke")
    .withPassword("duke");
```

As Testcontainers starts them on ephemeral ports, there's no conflict.

If you want two databases within the same database server, you can provide an init script that Testcontainers executed on container startup. With this script you can create the second database:

```
@Container
static final MariaDBContainer DATABASE =
  new MariaDBContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("mariadb:10.3.6"))
    .withDatabaseName("maindb")
    .withUsername("duke")
    .withPassword("duke")
    .withInitScript("CREATE_SECOND_DB.sql");
```

Where `CREATE_SECOND_DB.sql` is on your classpath with the following content:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DATABASE seconddb;
```

There are also further [Testcontainers initialization strategies](https://rieckpil.de/initialization-strategies-with-testcontainers-for-integration-tests/) to tweak your containers.